# What is the optimal use case for MQTT?

Tags: mqtt

I have a project that involves a backend communicating with numerous clients. I am searching for the optimal protocol to use. Is MQTT appropriate for my project?

Comment: how large is this project?

Comment: What kind of clients? Are they primary using mobile devices or web browsers? What kind of communication is your backend supposed to handle? How large will be the payload your clients send?

Answer (score 3):

Mqtt is best suited for projects involving numerous users. The objective is to provide a light-weight protocol optimized around a publish/subscribe model. It is the perfect protocol for your project because it will disseminate information throughout your user-base more rapidly than most other protocols.